# SQL date MM_YYYY

Tags: sql-server, converters, varchar, getdate

How do I convert a date to the following format?  `MM_YYYY` with an underscore instead of forward slashes or full stops?

I want to change this query to underscores:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105), 7) AS [MM-YYYY]
```

Thanks,

Jenny

Comment: What DB are yo using?

Comment: MSSQL I think, because of the commands.

Comment: **Why?** This is an issue of presentation and so should be handled by your presentation layer e.g. report, form, webpage, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your very same command with a replace:

```
SELECT replace(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105), 7),'-','_')
```

See it here at fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29554

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you could do something like

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()))
```